# "Lexical or Preprocessor" Issue with a new project in Qt Creator (C++ with Qt5)

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qt-creator

I'm using Qt Creator 4.11.1 on Windows 10.  This uses Qt 5.14.1.

I created a new project under Projects > Application > Qt Widgets Application.

Build System is CMake; I want to upload this to GitLab to do some basic CI.

Kit is "Desktop Qt 5.12.3 MSVC2017 64bit".

I'm trying to figure out if I'm missing something in my installation or something is not setup correctly.  I keep getting the following error after the project has just been created:

[image]

It can't find QApplication but I don't understand how that's possible if I setup everything correctly?

Comment: Did you add [find_package](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/cmake-get-started.html) in CMakeLists.txt to find Qt package? Also could you provide more info on your build kit settings?

Comment: find_package is automatically included through the setup.

I found out I had not selected the CMake options under Developer and Designer Tools.

That said now I'm having an error during a build saying:

"Failed to retrieve MSC Environment from "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat amd64"

Comment: To clarify, "find_package" is automatically included in CMakeLists.txt through the setup.

I made a QWidget with a main window to test the new project configuration, I have not added anything to the project.

Comment: Did you check whether vcvarsall.bat in present the above mentioned location?

Comment: can you share the `build settings` of the project. Are the Qt directories fields have proper value in them? Did you get any warnings during project configuration, you can check that in `General messages`.

Comment: Where would I get the build settings?  Are you looking for a file or just what my settings were that I described above?

And yes "vcvarsall.bat" exists exactly where it was looking, I had to start it manually in the command prompt to get rid of the error but that doesn't seem like a solution: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build>vcvarsall.bat x86_amd64 10.0.10240.0"